# GitLab showing computer name + router name as commiter name

Tags: git, gitlab, github-for-mac

I recently reinstalled GitHub Desktop (the Git client I use) and now all my commits I do to a GitLab projects show up from the username "[My mac username]@[My computer name].[Name of my router]" instead of the username I have in the GitLab installation.

What have I done wrong?
How can I fix this?

Comment: You're using GitHub Desktop but pushing to Gitlab?

Comment: Sounds crazy but (has) worked like a charm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git does commits entirely locally on your machine, the site you push those commits just reads them. So your Gitlab account has nothing to do with who you're committing as. This is critically important for the integrity of who did what and when.

What you're getting is the default username from Git. The Git command line client would normally issue you a warning and instructions:

```
$ git commit
[master (root-commit) cc46c07] Foo
 Committer: Michael Schwern <schwern@Windhund.local>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
```

Github Desktop likely has its own config. It will use your ***Github*** identity, not your Gitlab. Make sure you're logged in at Preferences->Accounts. Also check Preferences->Advanced and make sure your Git Config identity is correct.

Comment: Thank you, you totally saved my day!